# Handling exception stack trace while writing serial no in json logs using Json template layout log4j2

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am using [json template layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html) for writing json logs for my ecs service to s3 via kinesis firehose and firelens.

Following is the configuration for json template layout I am using -

```json
{
   "context_map": {
       "$resolver": "mdc"
   },
   "serial_no": {
     "$resolver": "pattern",
     "pattern": "%sn"
   },
   "timestamp": {
     "$resolver": "timestamp",
     "pattern": {
       "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
       "timeZone": "UTC"
     }
   },
   "level": {
     "$resolver": "level",
     "field": "name"
   },
   "logger_name": {
     "$resolver": "logger",
     "field": "name"
   },
   "message": {
     "$resolver": "message",
     "stringified": true
   },
   "thread": {
     "$resolver": "thread",
     "field": "name"
   },
   "exception": {
     "exception_class": {
       "$resolver": "exception",
       "field": "className"
     },
     "exception_message": {
       "$resolver": "exception",
       "field": "message",
       "stringified": true
     },
     "stacktrace": {
       "$resolver": "exception",
       "field": "stackTrace",
       "stringified": true
     }
   },
   "class": {
     "$resolver": "source",
     "field": "className"
   }
 }
```

Following is snapshot of log configuration -

```yaml
     Console:
       - Name: Console
         Target: SYSTEM_OUT
         JsonTemplateLayout:
           eventTemplateUri: "file:/opt/amazon/log-configuration/JsonLayoutTemplate.json"
           prettyPrintEnabled: true
           stackTraceEnabled: true
```

Following is the sample log generated in case of exception -

```json
{
    "container_id": "1f1319d278264d3dwewdeddewdewdewdew-849099158",
    "container_name": "test-container",
    "context_map": {
        "RequestId": "28289758-ab3b-4f8c-b3f1-freferfc"
    },
    "exception": {
        "exception_class ": "com.xyz.exception”,
        "exception_message": "Problem processing the SQS message with body helllo world, exception: Error while deserializing the message from test - message - queue.",
        "stacktrace": "com.xyz.exception: Problem processing the SQS message with body helllo world, exception: Error while deserializing the message from test - message - queue.\n\ .... stackTrace”
    },
    "level": "ERROR”,
    "logger_name": "com.xyz.handler",
    "message": "Seems to be impossible to process message: helllo world",
    "serial_no": "52 com.xyz.handler: Problem processing the SQS message with body helllo world, exception: Error while deserializing the message from test - message - queue.\n\ .... stackTrace",
    "source": "stdout",
    "thread": "test-thread",
    "timestamp": "2021-04-06 T14:30:02.122 Z"
}
```

As per the documentation `Pattern Resolver delegates to PatternLayout` and pattern layout provides `%sn` for getting sequence number.

We do need sequence number, since we can get a lot of logs simulatenously , so in order to differentiate between logs, we will be relying on sequence number, requestId params in those json logs while querying logs in AWS Athena.

Also, I have seen few log instances where the serial no is null (not the exception logs)

How can I prevent serial_no from including the exception stacktrace within it ?
And ensure that I always get serial_no field in the logs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you delegate from `JsonTemplateLayout` to `PatternLayout` via `pattern` resolver, the `LogEvent` is passed along as is. Once `PatternLayout` finds out that there is an exception attached to the `LogEvent`, it appends the stack trace to the emitted output, because the created `PatternLayout` instance inherited the `stackTraceEnabled=true` flag which you set for `JsonTemplateLayout`. Hence, you need to disable the stack traces for `PatternLayout` as follows:

```json
{
  "$resolver": "pattern",
  "pattern": "%sn",
  "stackTraceEnabled": false
}
```

Note that this will still produce sequence numbers of type `string`. If you want to produce sequence numbers of type `number`, you can use `timestamp` resolver in the following fashion:

```json
{
  "$resolver": "timestamp",
  "epoch": {
    "unit": "nanos",
    "rounded": true
  }
}
```

In the meantime, I have created [LOG4J2-3067](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3067) to add a sequence number resolver to `JsonTemplateLayout`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. Regarding the string vs number sequence numbers comment of yours, I understood that the timestamp resolver is for epochs. Can you please tell how we can cast sequence number to integer ? I mean we will still need pattern layout as resolver, right ?

Comment: `pattern` resolver output will always be rendered as a string by `JsonTemplateLayout`. Why don't you want to use the nanosecond-precision epochs provided by `timestamp` resolver, but stick to sequence numbers returned by `PatternLayout`?

Comment: Got it. Will use epochs provided by timestamp resolver. Thanks.

Comment: I tried using epochs but the json log contains the epoch in string only.

Comment: @AMANGUPTA, you need to have `rounded` flag on. Corrected the answer. The Log4j docs need to be updated to mention about `rounded`, created [LOG4J2-3071](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3071) to not forget about that.