# Prevent log4j2 JsonTemplateLayout from appending stack trace to other JSON fields

Tags: java, json, log4j2, stack-trace

I am using [JsonTemplateLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html) and have set up a JSON template that adds stack trace information to a `stack` field.

However, when logging exceptions, in addition to the stringified stack trace being placed in the stack field, it is also being appended to some of the other custom fields I have specified in the template.

I'm not sure which bit of configuration (or lack of configuration) is causing this.

I have not been able to locate a setting in the template that can avoid this.

Here is the template I have:

```
{
  "level": {
    "$resolver": "level",
    "field": "name"
  },
  "message": {
    "$resolver": "message",
    "stringified": true
  },
  "timestamp": {
    "$resolver": "timestamp",
    "pattern": {
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
      "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
  },
  "logger": {
    "$resolver": "logger",
    "field": "name"
  },
  "service": {
    "$resolver": "pattern",
    "pattern": "${env:FOO_SERVICE}"
  },
  "component": {
    "$resolver": "pattern",
    "pattern": "${env:FOO_COMPONENT}"
  },
  "exception": {
    "exception_class": {
      "$resolver": "exception",
      "field": "className"
    },
    "exception_message": {
      "$resolver": "exception",
      "field": "message"
    },
    "stacktrace": {
      "$resolver": "exception",
      "field": "stackTrace",
      "stackTrace": {
        "stringified": true
      }
    }
  },
  "line_number": {
    "$resolver": "source",
    "field": "lineNumber"
  }
}
```

The console appender is setup, and by default includes stack trace information. It references the above log4j2-layout which sits on the classpath.

```
<Appenders>
  <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:log4j2-layout.json"/>
  </Console>
</Appenders>
```

Here is an example of a logged exception. If you look closely, you'll see some fields such as `service` and `component` being set with their specified environment variable values, but they also have the stringified stack trace appended.

```
{"level":"INFO","message":"Force trigger exception","timestamp":"2022-11-02T20:37:35.270Z","logger":"foo.example.acme.system.connector.dataset.EchoAPI","service":"example1 java.lang.Exception: This is a forced exception\n\tat foo.example.acme.system.connector.dataset.EchoAPI.handle(EchoAPI.java:18) ~[classes/:?]\n\tat foo.example.acme.system.connector.ConnectorApi.handle(ConnectorApi.java:33) ~[classes/:?]\n\tat somesystem.com.connector.undertow.UndertowHandler.handleBody(UndertowHandler.java:131) ~[classes/:?]\n\tat io.undertow.io.AsyncReceiverImpl.receiveFullBytes(AsyncReceiverImpl.java:366) ~[undertow-core-2.2.19.Final.jar:2.2.19.Final]\n\tat somesystem.com.connector.undertow.UndertowHandler.handleRequest(UndertowHandler.java:61) ~[classes/:?]\n\tat io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387) ~[undertow-core-2.2.19.Final.jar:2.2.19.Final]\n\tat io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852) ~[undertow-core-2.2.19.Final.jar:2.2.19.Final]\n\tat org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35) ~[jboss-threads-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2019) ~[jboss-threads-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1558) ~[jboss-threads-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1423) ~[jboss-threads-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]\n\tat org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282) ~[xnio-api-3.8.7.Final.jar:3.8.7.Final]\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[?:?]\n","component":"example2 java.lang.Exception: This is a forced exception\n\tat foo.example.acme.system.connector.dataset.EchoAPI.handle(EchoAPI.java:18) ~[classes/:?]\n\tat foo.example.acme.system.connector.ConnectorApi.handle(ConnectorApi.java:33) ~[classes/:?]\n\tat somesystem.com.connector.undertow.UndertowHandler.handleBody(UndertowHandler.java:131) ~[classes/:?]\n\tat io.undertow.io.AsyncReceiverImpl.receiveFullBytes(AsyncReceiverImpl.java:366) ~[undertow-core-2.2.19.Final.jar:2.2.19.Final]\n\tat somesystem.com.connector.undertow.UndertowHandler.handleRequest(UndertowHandler.java:61) ~[classes/:?]\n\tat io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387) ~[undertow-core-2.2.19.Final.jar:2.2.19.Final]\n\tat io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852) ~[undertow-core-2.2.19.Final.jar:2.2.19.Final]\n\tat org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35) ~[jboss-threads-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2019) ~[jboss-threads-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1558) ~[jboss-threads-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1423) ~[jboss-threads-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]\n\tat org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282) ~[xnio-api-3.8.7.Final.jar:3.8.7.Final]\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[?:?]\n","exception":{"exception_class":"java.lang.Exception","exception_message":"This is a forced exception","stacktrace":"java.lang.Exception: This is a forced exception\n\tat foo.example.acme.system.connector.dataset.EchoAPI.handle(EchoAPI.java:18)\n\tat foo.example.acme.system.connector.ConnectorApi.handle(ConnectorApi.java:33)\n\tat somesystem.com.connector.undertow.UndertowHandler.handleBody(UndertowHandler.java:131)\n\tat io.undertow.io.AsyncReceiverImpl.receiveFullBytes(AsyncReceiverImpl.java:366)\n\tat somesystem.com.connector.undertow.UndertowHandler.handleRequest(UndertowHandler.java:61)\n\tat io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)\n\tat io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)\n\tat org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2019)\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1558)\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1423)\n\tat org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)\n"}}
```

I have also tried to set `stringified` to `false`, as well as setting up the custom fields that are being appended to, to be nested - e.g. `foo.component` and `foo.service` instead, but that didn't help either.

I am using the latest log4j2 version - 2.19.0 (also tried slightly older versions).

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for this behaviour after scouring stackoverflow for quite some time.

See: [Handling exception stack trace while writing serial no in json logs using Json template layout log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66973312/handling-exception-stack-trace-while-writing-serial-no-in-json-logs-using-json-t)

**tldr;**

The stack trace was being appended to all fields that used the `pattern` resolver.

e.g.

```json
"component": {
    "$resolver": "pattern",
    "pattern": "${env:FOO_COMPONENT}"
}
```

This was happening because `stackTraceEnabled` (true / enabled by default) was being inherited when delegating from the main `JsonTemplateLayout` to `PatternLayout` for each log event that included an exception stacktrace.

The quick fix is to disable it for each field that uses the `pattern` resolver.

e.g.

```json
"component": {
    "$resolver": "pattern",
    "pattern": "${env:FOO_COMPONENT}",
    "stackTraceEnabled": false
}
```